# Django и cron/celery

Tags: django

Задача: есть приложение на django и внешний сервис. Нужно отслеживать изменение значения одного поля во внешнем сервисе и как только оно сменится с false на true запустить в django выполнение скрипта, который отправит данные на третий сервис. Как безболезненно реализовать прослушку внешнего сервиса?

1. django_cron и по расписанию отправлять запросы на проверку значения поля.
2. celery и redis - очень мощный инструмент, который может и не нужен для некрупного проекта.

Я не делал ни 1, ни 2, поэтому спрашиваю совет в сторону чего смотреть и какой вариант будет проще в исполнении.

Comment: Я для одного из своих проектов использовал `django-apscheduler`.

Comment: Как вариант, https://code.google.com/archive/p/django-cron/